# SSL certificate working on same machine but not from different machine

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have a docker setup to run kafka broker with SSL.
A shell script is used to execute certificate generation steps and used that to enable ssl for kafka.

I am able successfully use keystore and trustore jks to access kafka broker in same machine.
(Both kafka tool and apache nifi has been configured as client[publisher/consumer] and it works fine)

But when I try to connect broker using these certs from different machine in same network, it gives error.
(Nifi says 'Invalid password or certificate type' but I feel this error message is misleading and reason could be different)

Any hint or idea what could be the reason ?

Getting below error when I tried using kafka toolkit :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:432)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:45)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /home/ubuntu/sslcertkafka/directtransfer/kafka_install/kafka.client.truststore.jks of type JKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:450)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:421)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /home/ubuntu/sslcertkafka/directtransfer/kafka_install/kafka.client.truststore.jks of type JKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSSLContext(SslEngineBuilder.java:163)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.<init>(SslEngineBuilder.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:69)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /home/ubuntu/sslcertkafka/directtransfer/kafka_install/kafka.client.truststore.jks of type JKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.load(SslEngineBuilder.java:292)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSSLContext(SslEngineBuilder.java:155)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:666)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:71)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.load(SslEngineBuilder.java:289)
```

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: maybe the subject of certificate not matching hostname of kafka?

Comment: @daggett - Thanks for your reply.


[alt_names]
DNS.1 = broker
DNS.2 = localhost
DNS.3 = ip-{my-ip-where-docker-running}.ec2.internal
IP.1 = {my-ip-where-docker-running}
IP.2 = 0.0.0.0

Above subject names I am adding, and kafka broker is running in docker container in my machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the keystore and truststore on different machines, make sure to provide the 2nd machine or machines with the key store that the system that works has. And then update the path. Not sure if this will solve it, but providing the same key and truststore and key and cert will definitely help.